# Concatenation in Verilog seemingly not using full width

Tags: verilog

Source code:

```
module main();
wire [31:0] a = 32'b0;
wire [25:0] a_man = {1'b1, a[24:0]};
initial begin
$display("%b\n%b\n%b", {1'b1,a[24:0]}, a_man[25:0], a_man);
end
endmodule
```

Actual output:

```
% iverilog dings.v && vvp a.out
10000000000000000000000000
1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I do not understand how come all bits of `a_man` are not assigned. I do not understand what the difference is, between doing the concatenation inline and doing it in the wire declaration.

Comment: Try `$monitor` instead of `$display` - could be a scheduling thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At modelsim SE-64 10.1d I have:

```
ModelSim> vsim work.main
# vsim work.main 
# ** Note: (vsim-3812) Design is being optimized...
# Loading work.main(fast)
run
# 10000000000000000000000000
# 10000000000000000000000000
# 10000000000000000000000000
```

As expected...

So: it's a tool issue, not a language one.

Comment: could I consider this a bug in Icarus Verilog?

Comment: You are displaying at time 0 this is very unreliable.

Comment: Per the answer from @Munkymorgy, this is not a tool issue, it's a zero-time initialization/scheduling problem. Put some #delay before the $display and see what you get.

Answer (score 5):

With experience you will learn not to trust any Verilog simulator at time 0. Always allow a minimum timestep for the simulator to assign your initial value.

```
module test;
wire [7:0] a     = 7'b0;
wire [7:0] a_man = {1'b1, a[6:0]};

initial begin
  $display("%b %b %b", {1'b1,a[6:0]}, a_man[7:0], a_man);
  #1fs;
  $display("%b %b %b", {1'b1,a[6:0]}, a_man[7:0], a_man);
  #1ns;
  $display("%b %b %b", {1'b1,a[6:0]}, a_man[7:0], a_man);
end
endmodule
```

Gives (ncsim):

```
1xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx
10000000 1xxxxxxx 1xxxxxxx
10000000 10000000 10000000
```